# Issue with plotting multiple axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to create a plot that shows a couple of variables (integers) on a single x axis (date), and having some issues getting the base created.
I keep getting the error message

> "Error in as.matrix(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default".

Here is all my code, if you can help it would be fantastic!

```
avail <- avail %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(avail$Date, format = "%a %d-%b-%Y"))
  avail <- format(avail, format="%d-%m-%Y")
  avail

names(avail)[2] <- "Available Jobs"

df <- data.frame("Date" = avail$Date,
                "Available Jobs" = avail$`Available Jobs`,
                "Jobs" = job$Jobs.Added,
                "Views" = view$Views)
```

##### This is the part that gives error messages:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=df$Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y=df$Available.Jobs), size=2, color=scale.default())+
  geom_line(aes(y=df$Views), size=2, color=scale.default())+
  scale_x_continuous(
    name= "Available Jobs",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "Views"))+
  ggtitle("September views against available jobs")
```

Comment: Don’t use `df$ColName` within your `ggplot` call. Just use the bare column name. For example `aes(x=Date))`

Comment: @Limey, it doesn't work without specifying the dataset. I'm not sure why but I get error messages either way

Answer (score 0):

"it doesn't work without specifying the dataset": well, with respect, then you're doing something wrong.  It turns out you're probably doing several things wrong...

You haven't given us a reprodicible example, so I can't be 100% sure of what you want, but here's a close as I can get.

First, create some data and load libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# For reproducibility
set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(
           Date=seq(ymd("2022-09-01"), ymd("2022-09-30"), "1 day"),
           `Available Jobs`=runif(30, 100, 200),
           Jobs=runif(30, 50, 150),
           Views=runif(30, 200, 300)
         )
```

Now attempt to create a plot.  I've commented where I've either corrected errors or made assumptions.

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=Date)) +
        # Note the correction to the name of the y variable
        # color=scale.default() is the source of the "as.matrix()" error
        geom_line(aes(y=`Available Jobs`), size=2, color="blue") +
        geom_line(aes(y=Views), size=2, color="red") +
        # Why label the x axis with the name of the y variable?  Is this change correct?
        scale_y_continuous(
          name= "Available Jobs",
          # Removing color=scale.default() introduces object 'coeff' not found here
          # sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "Views")
        ) +
        ggtitle("September views against available jobs")
```

[See?  No references to `df` inside the pipe.]  This gives:

[image]

Another problem may be that your data is (probably) not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) - because you have information in the *names* of your columns.  `ggplot` (and the rest of the tidyverse) expects tidy data, so you are attempting to fight against the tidyverse's expectations.  One way to make your data tidy and produce a similar plot might be:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(`Available Jobs`, Views),
    names_to="Metric",
    values_to="Value"
  ) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=Value, colour=Metric))
```

[image]

I've omitted some of the formatting of the plot to focus on the key issue: making your data tidy.

I've had to make guesses and assumptions in providing this answer, principally because you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example.